# Repeat background over the whole page, not only for the view area

Tags: html, css

I've got this background:

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 10% 0,
        rgba(74, 121, 147, 0.89),
        rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.85) 60%,
        rgba(185, 135, 131, 0.87) 120%)
        repeat scroll 0 0,
        url('../img/bgnoise.png') repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Works like a charm, but when I resize my browser window so that there is a horizontal scrollbar the background starts to repeat at the right and left edge of the window.
Is it possible to get this background for to whole page instead of the current view area?

**EDIT**

Forget to mention, sorry:
It's applied to the body-tag. Here is the whole css for the body:

```
body {
    min-width: 1000px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 10% 0,
        rgba(74, 121, 147, 0.89),
        rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.85) 60%,
        rgba(185, 135, 131, 0.87) 120%)
        repeat scroll 0 0,
        url('../img/bgnoise.png') repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: is this being applied to `body` or a `div` if its a div can you please provide your `css` for that `div`

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question.

Comment: Instead of setting a min-width and max-width on the body, why not set the body to 100% width, and then set a container div to your desired widths. Using the body as a container is generally bad practice

Comment: either the solution that @mituw16 suggested. or alternatively set a fixed position div as the background so that it scrolls with the page.

Comment: Thanks for your help @mituw16 - tried that but I get the same result.

Comment: You do have repeat set on the background. Is this intentional? @haxxxton's solution is usually a pretty good way to do a full page background. Check this page out, http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ .. I've used the `background:cover` trick before with success

Comment: seems to work for me if I apply it to a div: http://jsfiddle.net/N2TLD/2/

Comment: Yea this is intentional. My background image should repeat - its a 100x100 noise-picture. Here a screenshot what my problem actually is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37289435/bg_correct.png (how it looks at full-size) and here the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37289435/bg_fail.png

Comment: Have you tried putting the bg on the `html` element instead of the body?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below code snippet in the stylesheet.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
body{min-width:inherit;}
}
```

Comment: Same result - background begins to redraw outside the view area.

Answer (score -1):

Try with the below code snippet.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: ok. i got it wrong. I think min-width is creating trouble here. Try without min-width, it should work. i checked it at my end. its working